# iMac not working with wireless but mac book pro and hp probook is

Tags: macos, mac, wireless-networking, imac

I have a blinkin n600 wireless router set up with the bare bones settings. No static ips, just dhcp and wpa/wpa2 setup.

The internet on both the mac book bro and probook is working 100% fine, the mac book on wireless and probook through ethernet.

But when it comes to the iMac (which is running osx) it shows it is connected to the wireless. But there is no internet. There is no static ip address or firewalls stopping connection to the router or the internet.

I had the iMac working with an open network before that just had a hidden ssid and a static ip thing going on where only certain mac addresses would work with it.

If you need any more info just ask away.

Comment: What does the Network Diagnostics say? It is in System Preferences, then Network, (make sure that Wi-Fi is selected on the left), then Assist Me (on the bottom), then Diagnostics.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new login. Login as that user. Try the wireless again. If still not working go to system preferences, networking, highlight the wireless adapter then click the minus symbol on the bottom of the column. Apply then ok and reboot. Log back in as the new user and then go to system prefernces again and add the adapter again using the plus symbol at the bottom of the column. Now switch wireless on and try and connect - hopefully it will connect ok.

This completely resets and clears the wireless setup.